# Compile error in testbench with UVM (mtiRnm library)

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

I'm trying to compile a very basic testbench (that actually does nothing) with Modelsim 10.3b. However, I'm facing the error: `Error: (vlog-19) Failed to access library 'mtiRnm' at "mtiRnm".`

What I'm trying to compile is basically just a package similar to:

```
`ifndef __MY_PKG
`define __MY_PKG

package my_pkt;

    import uvm_pkg::*;
    `include "uvm_macros.svh"

endpackage : my_pkg

`endif
```

The error seems related to UVM because of, by commenting out the two uvm related lines, the error goes away. However, Modelsim is able to locate UVM because of the `include` line generates the warning `Note: (vlog-2286) Using implicit +incdir+/tools/MGS/modelsim_SE10.3b/modeltech/uvm-1.1d/../verilog_src/uvm-1.1d/src from import uvm_pkg`, so something is happening.

What can be the cause of the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying when you remove the import and include uvm, your code compiles, fine? Or does that produce a different set of errors which is probably making out the mtiRnm error?

Comment: Without them, the code compiles fine

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to delete the modelsim.ini file in the compilation folder...don't know what happened, but it works.